# Can FFmpeg crop gif image under 1 second?

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, gif

I am developing an iOS application about gif.

But I have a problem with gif cropping. Cropping gif spends so many times with FFmpeg.

(updated code)

These are the ffmpeg codes I've tried.

cropped images -> gif

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i %d.jpg -vf 'scale=450:-1' output.gif
```

using concat command (cropped images -> gif)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i tmp.txt output.gif
```

using crop filter

```
ffmpeg -i in.gif -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.gif
```

These codes are so slow when converting images to gif
or gif to cropped gif.

Is there a way to reduce the time to crop gif less than 1 second?

(updated2)
`ffmpeg -i in.gif -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.gif`

> ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
> built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared

> --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox   libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100   libavcodec     58.134.100 /
> 58.134.100   libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100   libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100   libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0   libswscale      5.  9.100 /
> 5.  9.100   libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100   libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100 Input #0, gif, from './test.gif':   Duration: 00:00:18.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 70098 kb/s   Stream #0:0:
> Video: gif, bgra, 1080x1920, 15 fps, 14.99 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
> Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> gif (native))
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help Output #0, gif, to './crop.gif':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavf58.76.100   Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgr8(pc, progressive), 1080x1198, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 14.99 fps, 100 tbn
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 gif frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.01 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=5e+03x

> frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:00.68
> bitrate=49344.8kbits/s speed=1.31x     frame=   22 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=    8192kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate=47594.9kbits/s speed=1.32x
> frame=   32 fps= 20 q=-0.0 size=   12288kB time=00:00:02.08
> bitrate=48395.8kbits/s speed=1.32x     frame=   43 fps= 20 q=-0.0
> size=   16384kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate=47764.3kbits/s speed=1.33x
> frame=   54 fps= 20 q=-0.0 size=   20992kB time=00:00:03.55
> bitrate=48441.3kbits/s speed=1.33x     frame=   65 fps= 20 q=-0.0
> size=   24832kB time=00:00:04.28 bitrate=47528.9kbits/s speed=1.35x
> frame=   77 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   28928kB time=00:00:05.08
> bitrate=46649.2kbits/s speed=1.36x     frame=   87 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   32768kB time=00:00:05.75 bitrate=46684.4kbits/s speed=1.36x
> frame=   98 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   36608kB time=00:00:06.48
> bitrate=46279.7kbits/s speed=1.36x     frame=  109 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   40704kB time=00:00:07.22 bitrate=46183.8kbits/s speed=1.37x
> frame=  120 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   44800kB time=00:00:07.95
> bitrate=46163.7kbits/s speed=1.37x     frame=  131 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   49152kB time=00:00:08.69 bitrate=46335.2kbits/s speed=1.38x
> frame=  142 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   53504kB time=00:00:09.42
> bitrate=46529.2kbits/s speed=1.37x     frame=  153 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   57344kB time=00:00:10.15 bitrate=46282.0kbits/s speed=1.38x
> frame=  164 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   61184kB time=00:00:10.89
> bitrate=46025.6kbits/s speed=1.38x     frame=  174 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   65280kB time=00:00:11.55 bitrate=46300.8kbits/s speed=1.37x
> frame=  185 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   69376kB time=00:00:12.29
> bitrate=46243.1kbits/s speed=1.38x     frame=  196 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   72960kB time=00:00:13.02 bitrate=45905.4kbits/s speed=1.38x
> frame=  207 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   76544kB time=00:00:13.76
> bitrate=45570.4kbits/s speed=1.38x     frame=  218 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   80640kB time=00:00:14.49 bitrate=45590.3kbits/s speed=1.38x
> frame=  229 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   84224kB time=00:00:15.23
> bitrate=45302.9kbits/s speed=1.39x     frame=  240 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   88064kB time=00:00:15.96 bitrate=45201.8kbits/s speed=1.39x
> frame=  250 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   91648kB time=00:00:16.63
> bitrate=45146.1kbits/s speed=1.39x     frame=  261 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> size=   96000kB time=00:00:17.36 bitrate=45301.4kbits/s speed=1.38x
> frame=  271 fps= 21 q=-0.0 size=   99840kB time=00:00:18.03
> bitrate=45362.7kbits/s speed=1.38x     frame=  274 fps= 21 q=-0.0
> Lsize=  101552kB time=00:00:18.23 bitrate=45634.2kbits/s speed=1.37x
> video:101552kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global
> headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000019%

it takes 12 seconds

Comment: Does not appear to be a log from ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan I updated all the ffmpeg code. I'm sorry to have confused you about the code.

Comment: It is slow because you are outputting GIF that is 1080x1198. Much bigger than most GIF. Output smaller size.

Comment: I didn't think about image size! Thanks a lot